# JQuery Ajax - Rebinding elements with the context param instead of delegate?

Tags: ajax, jquery

So we all know in an ajax update events must be rebound to new dom elements. Yes delegate is an option, but delegate doesn't work for all scenarios. For instance delegate won't help for  something that needs to be done simply on load rather than on a click event.

Rather than split my code into delegate handlers and handlers that need to be rebound on updates, I would rather define a single method with a context parameter that gets called every time the page changes like so:

```
function onPageUpdate(context) {
     $('a', context).click(...); // event handlers
     $('.chart', context).addClass(...); // load handlers

}
```

On dom ready this will be called with the context parameter null. On an ajax update the context will container the new dom elements. This way I'll never have to worry about delegating or ajax updates again.

I'm having trouble getting this to work however. Given the ajax callback:

```
function onSuccess(data) {
    // data contains new dom elements like: <div><a>Click</a><span>chart<span></div>
    // replace old elements with new ones
    $('a').replaceWith('a', data);
    $('span').replaceWith('span', data);

    // call pageUpdate with the new context
    onPageUpdate(data);
}
```

Is it possible to make this work like I expect? The replacing works fine, but onPageUpdate isn't binding anything to these new elements, I don't know if thats because the context is just a string object or what. Can anyone think of a way to make this work?

In my mind this is a better solution than delegate, because theres only one method for all handlers and only the elements that need a binding will own it.

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

> jQuery( selector [, context] )
>
> selector A string containing a selector expression
>
> context A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

If the context isn't the correct type - such as passing a string - it's simply going to be ignored. Try wrapping your HTML string in a jQuery object, then use that as the context for your selectors, like so:

```
var $context = $(data);
$('a').replaceWith('a', $context);
$('span').replaceWith('span', $context);

// call pageUpdate with the new context
onPageUpdate($context);
```

Comment: Well I tried this, but the bindings didn't appear to stick. This may be do to some object reference issues behind the scenes. One way I found it to work is to individually invoke the page method after every replacement with the new elements, like onPageUpdate($('a')), although that feels slower

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer to your question, Anthony Grist's answer is quite right, but there are some things you said that I don't understand. Could you explain them to me ?

> For instance delegate won't help for something that needs to be done simply on load rather than on a click event

Sorry but I don't get it, do you have an example ?

> In my mind this is a better solution than delegate, because theres
>   only one method for all handlers and only the elements that need a
>   binding will own it.

I don't get it too:

- `only one method`: which method are you talking about ?
- `only the elements ... will own it`: it's also the case with delegate, and more, if you have let's say 10 anchor element, only ONE handler would be bound, instead of 10 in your solution

On your method `onPageUpdate` you're mixing two things: event handling (`$("a").click(...)`) and DOM modification (`$(".char").addClass(...)`). Maybe that's why you're confusing about delegate's ability to resolve your problem.

Comment: In my example yes I am mixing event handling and dom modification. Both of these I wanted to handle in a single method, rather than a method for events and another method for load (that needs to be called on ajax updates as well). I was trying to call one method with a context param to handle that. Although I see your point that delegate will have less bound handlers than individually.

Comment: And the dom modification is my example for something delegate cant handle because you cant delegate a load event. That code needs to be invoked again on new dom elements.

Comment: OK I see your point, I didn't know about load/delegate problem. Why not split your code in two parts, first that works with event delegation (would be called only once), and second that doesn't work with event delegation and use your current system (called on page load and after each request). Event delegation is really powerful, so with this solution your application would be faster (less code executed initially and after request, less handler bound). OK that's 2 function to call, but the gain is big :) what do you think ?

Comment: Yes I'm starting to agree that two functions may be better performance wise even if its not as pretty as having one. I will still use the context solution though for the dom method, so this way it executes faster with a smaller context.

Comment: But it's pretty to use event delegation ! :)
About the context, you should use `$(context).find(selector)` which perfoms way better than `$(selector, context)`.
But of course the context thing must stay in because if you remove it, you could apply the function more than one time to the same element, which I think you don't want :)